# click on button using Stateflow works itself without any click

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have merged my code from livedata to stateflow to make some actions. Now I'm using StateFlow to navigate to another fragment, the problem is when I click on the button it is not working and when I used livedata it was worked!.

**Here's my code of viewmodel**

```
private val _habitsUIState = MutableStateFlow(HabitsMainUIState())
val habitsUIState: StateFlow<HabitsMainUIState> get() = _habitsUIState

private val _addHabitClickedEvent = MutableStateFlow(false)
val addHabitClickedEvent: StateFlow<Boolean> get() = _addHabitClickedEvent

private val _editHabitLongClickedEvent = MutableStateFlow(HabitUIState())
val editHabitLongClickedEvent: StateFlow<HabitUIState> get() = _editHabitLongClickedEvent

override fun onEditHabitLongClicked(habit: HabitUIState): Boolean {               _editHabitLongClickedEvent.value = habit return false 
}

fun onAddHabitClicked() { 
   _addHabitClickedEvent.value = true 
}
```

**and here is my code in fragment**

```
private fun observeEvents() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.apply {
            habitsUIState.collectLatest { habitsMainState ->
                habitsAdapter.setItems(habitsMainState.habits)
            }
            addHabitClickedEvent.collectLatest {
                navigateToAddHabitDialog()
            }
            editHabitLongClickedEvent.collectLatest { habitsUIState ->
                navigateToHabitEditingDialog(habitsUIState)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My button xml "I know it is not needed here but it is ok"**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_habit_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_button_style"
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onAddHabitClicked()}"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

When the code is in the state above, only the data is loaded, but the rest of the code in the lifecycleScope never work as if it has frozen!

When I tried moving each function into its own lifecycleScope (see the code down), they all worked at the same time, but some of them should work when a certain button is pressed.

```
private fun observeEvents() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.habitsUIState.collectLatest { habitsMainState ->
            habitsAdapter.setItems(habitsMainState.habits)
        }
    }
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.addHabitClickedEvent.collectLatest {
            navigateToAddHabitDialog()
        }
    }
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.editHabitLongClickedEvent.collectLatest { habitsUIState ->
            navigateToHabitEditingDialog(habitsUIState)
        }
    }
}
```

What problem am I facing and how can I solve it? thank you

I have tried using livedata and it was worked!